# I want to pass address on google map api for my project and show address in Google Map

Tags: android, google-maps

I have editText where I write addresss and get intent to next activity in this activity I want to pass address and after getting latitude and longitude I want to see on Google Map.

This is my code as well as asyn Class

```
public class GoOnMap extends FragmentActivity {

    GoogleMap googleMap;
    MarkerOptions markerOptions;
    LatLng latLng;
    static double lat;
    static double lng;
    String location;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.geotracking);

        SupportMapFragment supportMapFragment = (SupportMapFragment)
        getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);

        // Getting a reference to the map
        googleMap = supportMapFragment.getMap();
        Intent i=getIntent();
         location=i.getStringExtra("address");

    //getLocationInfo(location);
    new loadMap().execute(location);

    }

    public class loadMap extends AsyncTask<String , Integer, String> {


        public void getLatLongFromAddress() {

            new Thread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    String uri = "http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address="
                            + location + "&sensor=false";
                    HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(uri);
                    HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
                    HttpResponse response;
                    StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

                    try {
                        response = client.execute(httpGet);
                        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                        InputStream stream = entity.getContent();
                        int b;
                        while ((b = stream.read()) != -1) {
                            stringBuilder.append((char) b);
                        }
                    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
                    try {
                        jsonObject = new JSONObject(stringBuilder.toString());

                        lng = ((JSONArray) jsonObject.get("results"))
                                .getJSONObject(0).getJSONObject("geometry")
                                .getJSONObject("location").getDouble("lng");

                         lat = ((JSONArray) jsonObject.get("results"))
                                .getJSONObject(0).getJSONObject("geometry")
                                .getJSONObject("location").getDouble("lat");

                        Log.d("latitude", "" + lat);
                        Log.d("longitude", "" + lng);
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }).start();
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

             LatLng latLng = new LatLng(lat, lng);

             // Setting the position for the marker
             markerOptions.position(latLng);

             // Setting the title for the marker
             markerOptions.title("");

             // Placing a marker on the touched position
            googleMap.addMarker(markerOptions);

             // Locate the first location

                 googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng, 13));

        }


    }    


}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use Handler or AsyncTask for calling getting response from server:

Put getLatLongFromAddress() in same class,

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.geotracking);

    SupportMapFragment supportMapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map);

    // Getting a reference to the map
    googleMap = supportMapFragment.getMap();
    Intent i = getIntent();
    String location = i.getStringExtra("address");

    getLatLongFromAddress(location);
}

public void getLatLongFromAddress(String youraddress) {

    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            String uri = "http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address="
                    + youraddress + "&sensor=false";
            HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(uri);
            HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpResponse response;
            StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

            try {
                response = client.execute(httpGet);
                HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                InputStream stream = entity.getContent();
                int b;
                while ((b = stream.read()) != -1) {
                    stringBuilder.append((char) b);
                }
            } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
            try {
                jsonObject = new JSONObject(stringBuilder.toString());

                double lng = ((JSONArray) jsonObject.get("results"))
                        .getJSONObject(0).getJSONObject("geometry")
                        .getJSONObject("location").getDouble("lng");

                double lat = ((JSONArray) jsonObject.get("results"))
                        .getJSONObject(0).getJSONObject("geometry")
                        .getJSONObject("location").getDouble("lat");

                Log.d("latitude", "" + lat);
                Log.d("longitude", "" + lng);
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }).start();
}
```

AsyncTask:

```
public class loadMap extends AsyncTask < String, Integer, String > {

     loadMap()
     {

     }

     @Override
     protected String doInBackground(String...params) {
         // TODO Auto-generated method stub

         String uri = "http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=" + location + "&sensor=false";
         HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(uri);
         HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
         HttpResponse response;
         StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

         try {
             response = client.execute(httpGet);
             HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
             InputStream stream = entity.getContent();
             int b;
             while ((b = stream.read()) != -1) {
                 stringBuilder.append((char) b);
             }
         } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
             e.printStackTrace();
         } catch (IOException e) {
             e.printStackTrace();
         }

         JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
         try {
             jsonObject = new JSONObject(stringBuilder.toString());

             lng = ((JSONArray) jsonObject.get("results"))
                 .getJSONObject(0).getJSONObject("geometry")
                 .getJSONObject("location").getDouble("lng");

             lat = ((JSONArray) jsonObject.get("results"))
                 .getJSONObject(0).getJSONObject("geometry")
                 .getJSONObject("location").getDouble("lat");

             Log.d("latitude", "" + lat);
             Log.d("longitude", "" + lng);
         } catch (JSONException e) {
             e.printStackTrace();
         }
         return null;
     }

     @Override
     protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
         // TODO Auto-generated method stub

         LatLng latLng = new LatLng(lat, lng);

         // Setting the position for the marker
         markerOptions.position(latLng);

         // Setting the title for the marker
         markerOptions.title("");

         // Placing a marker on the touched position
         googleMap.addMarker(markerOptions);

         // Locate the first location

         googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng, 13));
     }
 }
```

Comment: thank you for giving me reply sir! ..  means  here I have to use this code inside async task???

Comment: Yes, you can use Handler ot AsyncTask?

Comment: Then you have to use String uri = "http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address="
                    + youraddress + "&sensor=false";................. code in AsyncTask

Comment: ok sir I write this code in async inside do in back ground  now for showing address on map  so which code should i use inside postExecute inside

Comment: After latitude-longitude received what you want?

Comment: means you want to see current latitude-longitude on map?

Comment: And for google map see example-http://javapapers.com/android/android-show-current-location-on-map-using-google-maps-api/

Comment: If you get solution from my answer, you can mark as right the answer.

Comment: ok sir but this type of error throws when i put on post method            E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.NullPointerException
E/AndroidRuntime(25561):  at com.FieldWorkMobility.GoOnMap$loadMap.onPostExecute(GoOnMap.java:117)
 E/AndroidRuntime(25561):  at com.cbsinfosys.FieldWorkMobility.GoOnMap$loadMap.onPostExecute(GoOnMap.java:1)
 android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:631)
 E/AndroidRuntime(25561):  at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:177)
 E/AndroidRuntime(25561):  at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:644)

Comment: @Override
  protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
   // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    googleMap.clear();
    LatLng latLng = new LatLng(lat, lng);
    
             
             markerOptions.position(latLng);

             
             markerOptions.title("");

             // Placing a marker on the touched position
            googleMap.addMarker(markerOptions);

             
            
                 googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng, 13))

Comment: @ManojYadav, did you craeted lat, lng as global?

Comment: can u tell me how to insert this code into doInBackground inside asynch...      actually inserted but i think its not executeing...thats why i am not getting lat,lng..

Comment: First of all check that, there are lat-long is null or not?

Comment: sir I Edited my question on top

Comment: I added AsyncTask on my answer, copy or paste on your code

Comment: sir its crashed the project ui says unfortunatly  <project> has stopped ...........       once map shows then project has crashed

Comment: I think you had make some mistake, that's why its crashing.

Comment: Visit this link for more detail- http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/locating-user-input-address-in-google-maps-android-api-v2-with-geocoding-api/

Comment: Its provides full source code, first of all you get idea about Google Map then implement in your code.

Comment: ok thanks a lot @Sagar Zala sir for giving your valuable time for me..I'll try with this link...

Comment: I worked out with this code that u give me link its was working fine but my project says that You shouldn't use different packages for parsing ....You have to pass address on to google and that will you the lal , lng .. thats why i have been working with this code..